# Android - IllegalStateException when sending get request in background

Tags: android, http, get

I want to send a get request in the background thread and have the following code:

```
public HttpResponse sendRequestInBackground(String clickUrl){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {        
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(clickUrl);
            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
            response = client.execute(request, context);
            Log.d("SEND_GET_REQUEST", "GET REQUEST SENT WITH URL: " + clickUrl);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

But keep getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'market' not registered.` Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would you please post your full activity code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used http://loopj.com/android-async-http/, and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating a background thread in this way you are just preventing your app from crashing by forcing to allow network operation on the main thread. An efficient way to do this kind of operation would be to use AsyncTask class. btw the code below for making a http get request works for me everytime.

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be these links would help you:

[Get the final URL of a redirected request with unconventional scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886313/get-the-final-url-of-a-redirected-request-with-unconventional-scheme)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/jh9HAbIUn48

[Android, how can i encapsulate an AsyncTask class with network connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561614/android-how-can-i-encapsulate-an-asynctask-class-with-network-connections)

[Query in AsyncTask giving illegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735224/query-in-asynctask-giving-illegalstateexception)

[Get the final URL of a redirected request with unconventional scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886313/get-the-final-url-of-a-redirected-request-with-unconventional-scheme)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL that is being sent is in the incorrect format. I'd guess that your URL is something like this: `market://details?id=com.example.bacon` which is not a valid URL. If you are attempting to open the Play Store to an application you want to use an Intent instead.

Like this (where com.example.bacon is your application's package name):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.bacon")); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Without more code posted that's the best that I can do.